# Adding a pandas column based on grouped counts of another column?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a pandas dataframe containing:

```
    Visited   PersonId
0   GB        1
1   US        1
2   US        1
3   GB        1
4   DE        1
5   CN        2
6   US        2
7   GB        3
8   GB        4
```

What's the most straightforward way to add a new column that contains a count of the unique number of countries visited for each PersonId?

E.g., for the above, person 1 has visited 3 different countries.  The new dataframe after adding the new column should look as follows for the above data:

```
    Visited   PersonId    CountryCount
0   GB        1           3
1   US        1           3
2   US        1           3
3   GB        1           3
4   DE        1           3
5   CN        2           2
6   US        2           2
7   GB        3           1
8   GB        4           1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works but I feel there is a better method

```
In [104]:

df['CountryCount'] = df['PersonId'].map(df.groupby(['PersonId'])['Visited'].unique().apply(len))
df
Out[104]:
  Visited  PersonId  CountryCount
0      GB         1             3
1      US         1             3
2      US         1             3
3      GB         1             3
4      DE         1             3
5      CN         2             2
6      US         2             2
7      GB         3             1
8      GB         4             1
```

Comment: nice. I was looking for something like SQL window functions, but haven't found anything yet

Comment: `.nunique` works too:

`df['PersonId'].map(df.groupby(['PersonId'])['Visited'].nunique())`

Comment: Yes, sorry, after I read your nice answer I forgot to refresh the page before posting.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this could be more elegant, but this works

```
>>> g = df.groupby('PersonId')['Visited'].nunique().reset_index()
>>> g.columns = ['PersonId', 'CountryCount']
>>> pd.merge(df, g)
  Visited  PersonId  CountryCount
0      GB         1             3
1      US         1             3
2      US         1             3
3      GB         1             3
4      DE         1             3
5      CN         2             2
6      US         2             2
7      GB         3             1
8      GB         4             1
```

Or, as @EdChum suggested in comments, it could be shortened to

```
df['CountryCount'] = df['PersonId'].map(df.groupby('PersonId')['Visited'].nunique())
```

Just in case, I've checked time of execution for all answers. While I don't think it really matters in OP case, turned out that @EdChum method is clear winner here:

```
In [7]: %timeit df["CountryCount"] = df.groupby("PersonId")["Visited"].transform(pd.Series.nunique)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.32 ms per loop

In [8]: %timeit df['CountryCount'] = df['PersonId'].map(df.groupby('PersonId')['Visited'].nunique())
100 loops, best of 3: 2.52 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit df['CountryCount'] = df['PersonId'].map(df.groupby(['PersonId'])['Visited'].unique().apply(len))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 ms per loop
```

After additional testing, I've found that combination of @DSM and @EdChums works even faster :)

```
In [26]: %timeit df["CountryCount"] = df.groupby("PersonId")["Visited"].transform(lambda x: x.unique().size)
1000 loops, best of 3: 952 µs per loop
```

[`Here's`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7771) somehow related issue on a github.

Comment: You could shorten to `df['CountryCount'] = df['PersonId'].map(df.groupby('PersonId')['Visited'].nunique())` and avoid the merge

Comment: hm yep. Then our answers will be almost the same :)

Comment: I think using `nunique` is better than calling `apply(len)` though ;) +1

Comment: @RomanPekar IMHO, I think you should edit to avoid the merge part and put the nunique(), which looks great.

Comment: @EdChum check out timings, `nunique()` is worse than `apply(len)` :)

Comment: @RomanPekar this is only faster probably for this small dataset I reckon but it is a little surprising

Answer (score 2):

When you want to "broadcast" across a group, you typically use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation):

```
>>> df["CountryCount"] = df.groupby("PersonId")["Visited"].transform(pd.Series.nunique)
>>> df
  Visited  PersonId CountryCount
0      GB         1            3
1      US         1            3
2      US         1            3
3      GB         1            3
4      DE         1            3
5      CN         2            2
6      US         2            2
7      GB         3            1
8      GB         4            1
```

Comment: I think transform is a correct way to use here, and this also a fastest on if we use `unique().size` instead of `nunique()`